# Get the largest embed/object in a page i.e. largest dimensions

Tags: javascript, html, object, embed

Could someone show me how to get th largest `embed` or `object` in an web page which has the largest dimensions. I need to be able to do this without any JS libraries.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you have every `<embed>` element in an `<object>` ([working example](http://jsbin.com/edebu4)):

```
function largestFlash() {
  var all = document.getElementsByTagName("object");
  var largest, largest_dimension = 0;
  for (var i = all.length; i--;) {
    var width  = parseInt(all[i].width,  10);
    var height = parseInt(all[i].height, 10);
    var dimension = width * height;
    if (dimension > largest_dimension) {
      largest = all[i];
      largest_dimension = dimension;
    }
  }
  return largest;
}
```